# Prevent Access in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone let me know how to prevent access to pages unless registered. At the moment the only restriction to all pages is h registered. So if a user becomes registered to view one page they're then given permission to view ALL pages on my site. See images. However, I would like only certain pages to be registered while other sites remain registered permanently.

I hope I'm making sense.

Cheers
[image: registration]

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to restrict certain pages for non-logged in users?

Comment: Webchun thanks for responding. That is correct. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new article, there's 'Access' option in the sidebar. Switch it to 'Registered'

[image: Screenshot]

Next, go to Menus, and edit the category blog menu item. Go to Options tab and set Show Unauthorised Links option to Yes

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The problem is that when I allow access to one registered page all pages are allowed access. Basically, I want some pages to be visible in a menu but when someone try's to access the page they need to authorised or registered.

Comment: So do you want the link for the article is visible somewhere in your website menu/navigation so then when the menu item is clicked the page will tell user to login , OR ...  you want the intro text of the article visible in the article list / blog view and then when it's clicked the will tell user to login?

Comment: That's it yes. I think that will work. A

Comment: Sorry webchun, I meant I would like the intro text of the article visible in the article list / blog view and then when it's clicked the will tell user to login. Cheers

Comment: Can someone help me sort this out?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please try

Comment: webchun, unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: It should be work, please make sure you are editing the correct menu item, the menu you use to display the article list

Comment: webchun, so may be what I want is the link for the article is visible somewhere in my website menu/navigation so then when the menu item is clicked the page will tell user to login